# Exponential backoff: time.sleep with random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000

Tags: python

In many google api's code samples i have seen this line of code.

```
time.sleep((2 ** n) + (random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000))
```

`random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000` always return random milliseconds.

Whats is the use of this random milliseconds ?

Comment: In Python 2, (random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)) will always return 0 (integer division returns an integer). Also, personally, I'd cap the exponential backoff, otherwise some of your clients may be waiting an undesirably long time. I'd use: min(64, (2 ** n)) + (random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000.0)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Having a bit of randomness in situations like this is good. For example, if you have a large number of clients hitting the same server, having them use the same deterministic backoff could result in them hitting the server in perfect lockstep, which isn't desirable.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is explained the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors?hl=pt-pt):

> In the above flow, random_number_milliseconds is a random number of
>   milliseconds less than or equal to 1000. This is necessary to avoid
>   certain lock errors in some concurrent implementations. The value of
>   random_number_milliseconds must be redefined after each wait.

This is a common technique to "fuzz" the timing of APIs accesses to avoid thrashing caused by falling into recurring patterns of resource lock acquisition and release.